# Custom filter API Platform not working

Tags: api-platform.com

I am trying to implement a custom or-filter in API Platform. But for some reason it is not loading. Find below my configuration.

This is my filter:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

final class SearchFilter extends AbstractFilter
{
    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
    if ($property === 'search') {
        $this->logger->info('Search for: ' . $value);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    $reader = new AnnotationReader();
    $annotation = $reader->getClassAnnotation(new \ReflectionClass(new $resourceClass), \AppBundle\Filter\SearchAnnotation::class);

    if (!$annotation) {
        throw new \HttpInvalidParamException('No Search implemented.');
    }

    $parameterName = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName($property);
    $search = [];
    $mappedJoins = [];

    foreach ($annotation->fields as $field)
    {
        $joins = explode(".", $field);
        for ($lastAlias = 'o', $i = 0, $num = count($joins); $i < $num; $i++) {
            $currentAlias = $joins[$i];
            if ($i === $num - 1) {
                $search[] = "LOWER({$lastAlias}.{$currentAlias}) LIKE LOWER(:{$parameterName})";
            } else {
                $join = "{$lastAlias}.{$currentAlias}";
                if (false === array_search($join, $mappedJoins)) {
                    $queryBuilder->leftJoin($join, $currentAlias);
                    $mappedJoins[] = $join;
                }
            }

            $lastAlias = $currentAlias;
        }
    }

    $queryBuilder->andWhere(implode(' OR ', $search));
    $queryBuilder->setParameter($parameterName, '%' . $value . '%');
}

/**
 * @param string $resourceClass
 * @return array
 */
public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
{
    $reader = new AnnotationReader();
    $annotation = $reader->getClassAnnotation(new \ReflectionClass(new $resourceClass), \AppBundle\Filter\SearchAnnotation::class);

    $description['search'] = [
        'property' => 'search',
        'type' => 'string',
        'required' => false,
        'swagger' => ['description' => 'Filter on ' . implode(', ', $annotation->fields)],
    ];

    return $description;
}
}
```

In api_filters.yml:

```php
driver.custom_search_filter:
    class: 'AppBundle\Filter\SearchFilter'
    autowire: true
    tags: [ { name: 'api_platform.filter' } ]
```

In my annotation file:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Filter;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
final class SearchAnnotation
{
    public $fields = [];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param array $data Key-value for properties to be defined in this class.
     * @throws AnnotationException
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        if (!isset($data['value']) || !is_array($data['value'])) {
            throw new AnnotationException('Options must be a array of strings.');
        }

        foreach ($data['value'] as $key => $value) {
            if (is_string($value)) {
                $this->fields[] = $value;
            } else {
                throw new AnnotationException('Options must be a array of strings.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in my entity:

```php
    /**
 * A driver that bring meals from hub to customer.
 *
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *         "filters"={"driver.search_filter","driver.custom_search_filter"},
 *         "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"post_driver"}}
 *     }
 * )
 * @Searchable({"firstName"})
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="vendor_driver")
 */
class Driver
{
```

It is exactly as according to the issue that was reported here:
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/398

I am not getting any errors, but the filter is simply not working. I am seeing it in Swagger. But when I enter a value in Swagger, the db returns all entities. Its never reaching the filterProperty method.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I've just managed to get this working by removing the autowiring, e.g.

```
my.custom_search_filter:
    class: AppBundle\Filter\CustomSearchFilter
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine'
        - '@request_stack'
        - '@logger'
    tags: [ { name: 'api_platform.filter', id: 'search' } ]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am seeing that @request_stack is null and therefor its still not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your custom filter in the Driver entity? In Regexp example of custom filter and [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/398) they are explicitly import their custom filters like:

```
use AppBundle\Filter\SearchAnnotation as Searchable;

/**
 * @Searchable({"name", "description", "whatever"})
 */

class Product
{
```

Comment: do you have a documentation to learn how to use perfectly custom filters ?

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara Only filters section in a main Api Platform docs https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/ and searching with "custom filter" keyword in the Github issues.

Comment: how can i apply this filter to an abstract class ?